# probability of occurrence a faulty job in final output in a chained queue(2 queue) when each queue has probability of generating a faulty job (b)

Tags: probability

Consider we have a chained queue:

*-> q1 ->q2 -> final output*

the probability of generating a faulty job in each queue is **b**

Now, What's the probability of a faulty job in **final output**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the probability of a good job in each stage is $1-b$, the probability of a good job after two stages is $(1-b)^2$, assuming stages are independent.  Therefore the probability of a fault at the end is $1-(1-b)^2=2b-b^2$.

Comment: So we can consider the probability of a faulty job b then for 2 independent queue we have b^2. it's opposite to your solution !

Comment: The problem was posed as two queues in sequence, so a job will be faulty if it fails on either one.  Your answer $b^2$ requires failure in both.